# Slice to fixed-size array

Tags: rust

I have a structure with some fixed-sized arrays:

```
struct PublicHeaderBlock_LAS14 {
    file_signature: [u8; 4],
    file_source_id: u16,
    global_encoding: u16,
    project_id_data_1: u32,
    project_id_data_2: u16,
    project_id_data_3: u16,
    project_id_data_4: [u8; 8],
    version_major: u8,
    version_minor: u8,
    systemIdentifier: [u8; 32], // ...
}
```

I'm reading in bytes from a file into a fixed size array and am copying those bytes into the struct bit by bit.

```
fn create_header_struct_las14(&self, buff: &[u8; 373]) -> PublicHeaderBlock_LAS14 {
    PublicHeaderBlock_LAS14 {
        file_signature: [buff[0], buff[1], buff[2], buff[3]],
        file_source_id: (buff[4] | buff[5] << 7) as u16,
        global_encoding: (buff[6] | buff[7] << 7) as u16,
        project_id_data_1: (buff[8] | buff[9] << 7 | buff[10] << 7 | buff[11] << 7) as u32,
        project_id_data_2: (buff[12] | buff[13] << 7) as u16,
        project_id_data_3: (buff[14] | buff[15] << 7) as u16,
        project_id_data_4: [buff[16], buff[17], buff[18], buff[19], buff[20], buff[21], buff[22], buff[23]],
        version_major: buff[24],
        version_minor: buff[25],
        systemIdentifier: buff[26..58]
    }
}
```

The last line (`systemIdentifier`) doesn't work, because in the struct it is a `[u8; 32]` and `buff[26..58]` is a slice. Can I return convert a slice to a fixed sized array like that over a range, instead of doing what I've done to say `file_signature`?

Comment: I've been trying to create a `make_array<A>(slice: &[T]) -> A`... and so far I have not succeeded.

Comment: I've asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678698/function-to-build-a-fixed-sized-array-from-slice to see if someone had a clue how to make this helper worked; it would greatly simplify things here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Edit: Since Rust 1.34, you can use `TryInto`, which is derived from [`TryFrom<&[T]> for [T; N]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html#impl-TryFrom%3C%26%5BT%5D%3E-for-%5BT%3B%20N%5D)

```rust
struct Foo {
    arr: [u8; 32],
}

fn fill(s: &[u8; 373]) -> Foo {
    // We unwrap here because it will always return `Ok` variant
    let arr: [u8; 32] = s[26..68].try_into().unwrap();
    Foo { arr }
}
```

Original answer from 2016:

There is no `safe` way to initialize an array in a struct with a slice. You need either resort to `unsafe` block that operates directly on uninitialized memory, or use one of the following two initialize-then-mutate strategies:

Construct an desired array, then use it to initialize the struct.

```
struct Foo {
    arr: [u8; 32],
}

fn fill(s: &[u8; 373]) -> Foo {
    let mut a: [u8; 32] = Default::default();
    a.copy_from_slice(&s[26..58]);
    Foo { arr: a }
}
```

Or initialize the struct, then mutate the array inside the struct.

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Foo {
    arr: [u8; 32],
}

fn fill(s: &[u8; 373]) -> Foo {
    let mut f: Foo = Default::default();
    f.arr.copy_from_slice(&s[26..58]);
    f
}
```

The first one is cleaner if your struct has many members. The second one may be a little faster if the compiler cannot optimize out the intermediate copy. But you probably will use the `unsafe` method if this is the performance bottleneck of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :) I've gone the safe way, as performance isn't necessary for this part of my lib - just loading/parsing different files.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [@malbarbo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37679019/147192) we can use this helper function:

```
use std::convert::AsMut;

fn clone_into_array<A, T>(slice: &[T]) -> A
    where A: Sized + Default + AsMut<[T]>,
          T: Clone
{
    let mut a = Default::default();
    <A as AsMut<[T]>>::as_mut(&mut a).clone_from_slice(slice);
    a
}
```

to get a much neater syntax:

```
fn main() {
    let original = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    let e = Example {
        a: clone_into_array(&original[0..4]),
        b: clone_into_array(&original[4..10]),
    };

    println!("{:?}", e);
}
```

as long as `T: Default + Clone`.

It will `panic!` if the target array and the passed-in slice do not have the same length, because `clone_from_slice` does.