# Ergonomics issues with fixed size byte arrays in Rust

Tags: rust, unsafe

Rust sadly cannot produce a fixed size array `[u8; 16]` with a fixed size slicing operator `s[0..16]`.  It'll throw errors like "expected array of 16 elements, found slice".

I've some KDFs that output several keys in wrapper `struct`s like

```
pub struct LeafKey([u8; 16]);
pub struct MessageKey([u8; 32]);

fn kdfLeaf(...) -> (MessageKey,LeafKey) {
    // let mut r: [u8; 32+16];
    let mut r: (MessageKey, LeafKey);
    debug_assert_eq!(mem::size_of_val(&r), 384/8);
    let mut sha = Sha3::sha3_384();
    sha.input(...);

    // sha.result(r);
    sha.result( 
      unsafe { mem::transmute::<&mut (MessageKey, LeafKey),&mut [u8;32+16]>(&r) } 
    );
    sha.reset();

    // (MessageKey(r[0..31]), LeafKey(r[32..47]))
    r
}
```

Is there a safer way to do this?  We know `mem::transmute` will refuse to compile if the types do not have the same size, but that only checks that pointers have the same size here, so I added that `debug_assert`.

In fact, I'm not terribly worried about extra copies though since I'm running SHA3 here, but afaik rust offers no ergonomic way to copy amongst byte arrays.

Can I avoid writing `(MessageKey, LeafKey)` three times here?  Is there a type alias for the return type of the current function?  Is it safe to use `_` in the `mem::transmute` given that I want the code to refuse to compile if the sizes do not match?  Yes, I know I could make a type alias, but that seems silly.

As an aside, there is a longer discussion of `s[0..16]` not having type `[u8; 16]` [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1772)

Comment: Oops.  I need to take a reference to the result of `unsafe`, but you get the idea :  I do not want to `mem::transmute` a pointer.

Comment: You should [edit] your own question instead of commenting to yourself.

Comment: In fact, I must `mem:transmute` the reference since I need to pass the reference to `sha.result()`, but maybe I can find a safer way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the `copy_from_slice` method.

```
fn main() {
    use std::default::Default;

    // Using 16+8 because Default isn't implemented
    // for [u8; 32+16] due to type explosion unfortunateness
    let b: [u8; 24] = Default::default();
    let mut c: [u8; 16] = Default::default();
    let mut d: [u8; 8] = Default::default();

    c.copy_from_slice(&b[..16])
    d.copy_from_slice(&b[16..16+8]);
}
```

Note, unfortunately `copy_from_slice` throws a **runtime** error if the slices are not the same length, so make sure you thoroughly test this yourself, or use the lengths of the other arrays to guard.

Unfortunately, `c.copy_from_slice(&b[..c.len()])` doesn't work because Rust thinks `c` is borrowed both immutably and mutably at the same time.

Comment: Yup, that's way more ergonomic than anything I'd seen.  Thanks!  I'll probably keep my `unsafe` for now, but if it starts to bug me than I'll look into doing a workaround with this.

Comment: Just found a nice helper function `clone_into_array` in http://stackoverflow.com/a/37679442/667457 that lets me use almost the idiomatic commented out lines.

Answer (score 0):

I marked the accepted answer as best since it's safe, and led me to the `clone_into_array` answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37679442/667457), but..

Another idea that improves the safety is to make a version of `mem::transmute` for references that checks the sizes of the referenced types, as opposed to just the pointers.  It might look like :

```
#[inline]
unsafe fn transmute_ptr_mut<A,B>(v: &mut A) -> &mut B {
    debug_assert_eq!(core::mem::size_of(A),core::mem::size_of(B));
    core::mem::transmute::<&mut A,&mut B>(v)
}
```

I have [raised an issue on the arrayref crate](https://github.com/droundy/arrayref/issues/5) to discuss this, as arrayref might be a reasonable crate for it to live in.

*Update* : We've a new "best answer" by the arrayref crate developer :

```
let (a,b) = array_refs![&r,32,16];
(MessageKey(*a), LeafKey(*b))
```